# Best way to get more accurate results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, search, procedure, temporary

I'm facing a dilema on a development environment.  It's a three table estructure:

1. Table Content (articles, news...)
2. Table Tags (tags for every article and news records)
3. Table Skip Words (words like "for", "get", "to"...)

The main idea is get the content records according to a text search, How?

**First**, removing words from the text search according to *Skip Words* table, and then match the rest of the words with the tags table.  However, I'd like to give a "smarter" result, as a

**second** step, I'd like to first get the articles that match with all the remaining words of the text search. This records would be the primary print.

**Third** step, if the there's no matching records with all the words of the text search, then start looking for records that match fewer words and keep a count of them, and so on until I get a list of content records.

The **last** step is showing those records ordered according to the amount of word matching.  So, considering this process I thought using:

1. Temporary table to load the data from all the steps mentioned
2. Using one single stored procedure with all the logic needed

*The above comparing the tags, using "Like" conditions* ( `and field like "word1%" and field like "word2%"` )

However, my concern is the performance. This would be a process in a main page Website, which has more than 1700 visits per hour.  I'd appreciate you could explain your experience about this kind of process (if had any)? or which do you think would be the best way to implement considering performance?

Comment: 1000 visits a day is nothing, dont worry until you get 1000 visits a minute

Comment: It should be OK when using a wildcard at the end of the pattern. It would be a problem if it was at the beginning od the pattern. Make sure the search columns are indexed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited it.  The website gets (average) 1700 visits per hour!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FULLTEXT` index.  It covers some of the ideas you are trying to re-invent.  1700/hr will be no problem.

```
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('join*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

matches join / joining / joined and joint.

Comment: Actually FULLTEXT index crossed my mind, but according to my research, this index allows the  wildcard use, but the thing is, for instance, if I look 'join*', it'll find the records with including words like 'joins', 'joining', etc. But I need the other way around, I need a tag "joi" so it'll be available to do the LIKE -> where "joins" like concat(tag,"%")  <- in case the user types "join", "joins" or "joining". The three words will return the same record, but I think with FULLINDEX I can't achieve this kind of solution.  am I right?

Comment: @Andino - I added an example of `"join*" in boolean mode`

Comment: Thank you for the example @RickJames.  But what I need is exactly the opposite.  For instance, if the user types "joining", I need to compare it against the column.  In the indexed column we'd find only "joi" inside the text. So, is there a way I can use, for example MATCH(col) but using a wildcard, like `MATCH(concat(col,"*"))` or somethink like that?.   This is because It's not functional for me to look for all the combinations of "join" and add them inside the column with FULLTEXT index